# Run a function before triggering x-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

How can I run some code before triggering xeditable? And prevent the default behavior depending on the result?

```
$('#costumer_phone').editable({
    name: 'number',
    // THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE
    onClick: function(e){
        if (var == true){
           e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `init` event.Please try as shown below.

> Fired when element was initialized by $().editable() method. Please
>   note that you should setup init handler before applying editable.

```
$('#costumer_phone').on('init', function(e, editable) {
     if (var == true){
           e.preventDefault();
        }
});
$('#costumer_phone').editable();
```